# Why does iTunes stick on "Waiting for sync to start" when using WiFi sync?

Tags: macos, ios, itunes, wifi, data-synchronization

Sometimes I get "Looking for iPhone" and then a silent failure. Sometimes it finds the iPhone and sticks on "Waiting for sync to start" long enough (more than 10 minutes) that I forget and/or try to quit iTunes. When I try to quit I usually have to force-quit if I actually want to get out of iTunes. I never get any error messages, just silent failures or iTunes frozen/not responding.

Sometimes a force-quit and relaunch gets things going, sometimes not. Just now after a force-quit/restart iTunes silently gave up after looking for the iPhone about 4 times and on the 5th try finally worked fine.

iPhone is on the same wifi network as the Mac running iTunes.

Comment: Note to self: it took about 30 mins for mine to move to step 2. I'm using the new Catalina app setup.